# woo-commerce- product visible location based

Tags: wordpress

I want to add product as location based means a person can see only those product which are available in his city woo commerce is providing location division as per country bases but I want it as city-wise. Suggest any plugins or any solution because i am having a multi-vendor site.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Product Visibility by Country for WooCommerce plugin might do the job for you: https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-visibility-by-country-for-woocommerce/